# ReactJS/ES6: Equivalence between two blocks of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently going through the ReactJS tutorial given [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/implementing_notes/), and I observed a particular shorthand that I could not quite follow.

```
export default ({task}) => <div>{task}</div>;
```

The author gives the above line of code as shorthand for the code I've written below, which I believe works the same way.

```
export default class Note extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.task}</div>;
   } 
}
```

I've tried to look up React documentation to figure out how the shorthand is handled to little avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation for components ["Stateless Functions"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions):

> You may also define your React classes as a plain JavaScript function. For example using the stateless function syntax ...

So in your case it works because you are using just a plain function instead of class. ES2015 syntax here is basically translates to:

```
export default function(task) {
    return <div>{task}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. For clarification, in the example given, `props` is passed as an argument to the stateless function, whereas in my example `{task}` is passed as an argument. Could you explain why this works?

Comment: Never mind! This is just the destructuring feature introduced in ES2015!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below mentioned link of babel in that mentioned the all different between in ES5 and ES6

[babel](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/)

Comment: Thanks for the resource!